# e.target() not working for table element

Tags: javascript, jquery

The `event.target` function works well for div and not for table element.

html code:

```
<div class="one body" >
    sd
    </div>
<div class="two body">
    sddsd
</div>
    <table width="100%"  border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="three body">jjj</table>
```

js:

```
$(".body").click(function(e){


    alert("xxxxxxxxx"+e.target.className);
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/kavinhuh/z4rkW/31/

Comment: Your HTML for your table is invalid.  The `jjj` isn't actually rendered inside the table.  You need (a `<tbody>` and then) a `<tr>` and finally a `<td>`.

Comment: Thank you all for your very helpful comments,I love stack overflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cause the actual e.target is a TD, not a table
Though you have an incorrect Table HTML Element structure. Tables are expected to have `tr` and `td` elements.

```
alert("Class: "+ event.target.className );
```

// is the Element that first fired the event ( `TD` )

```
alert("Class: "+ this.className );
```

// is the element that was delegated to the event, in this case `.body`

Comment: Which browser puts the text inside a `td`? Chrome puts it outside the `table` altogether.

Comment: @lonesomeday doh, right. Thought that like browsers automatically add <tbody> did the same job here. Inspected and that's right. FF acts the same way. Any way I was about to test, you were just faster ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is because your HTML is illegal. If you have illegal HTML, you should not expect your code to work properly.

Text may not be a direct child of a `table`. You need a `tr` and either a `td` or a `th`. The browser reinterprets your HTML and makes something  legal. In this case, it puts the text outside the table:

```
    jjj
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="three body"></table>
```

This is taken from Chrome's DOM inspector. The solution is to put the text legally inside the `table`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `this` instead of `e.target` .

`e.target` will give you the clicked element, not the element where the event has been attached to. When the element where the event has been attached to has child-elements this and you click on a child-element `e.target` will return the child-element.

```
alert(this.className);
```

Answer (score 1):

`table` elements cannot have any text content so, your html will actually be rendered as

```
  <div class="one body">
    sd
    </div>
<div class="two body">
    sddsd
</div>
    jjj<table class="three body" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%"></table>
```

Which is why your event handler is not firing when you click on `jjj`